# How to print table in the second page if it does not fit entirely in the first one

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a little issue with my report. I have four tables whose data are variables (not fixed. They depends on the dataset). All the tables have a tableHeader which works as table's title. As output I want that the 3rd and the 4th table get printed in the second page if they are not fit in the fist one (the first two tables have to push the 3rd and the 4th down, till the 2nd page). On the contrary, the actual behavior of my reports is different. The 1st and the 2nd tables are printed in the 1st page and just a few rows of the 3rd and the 4th table are printed in te 2nd page.

[image]

I can I solve that?

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
<group name="Group1" minHeightToStartNewPage="410">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[true]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="249">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="812" height="249" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" forecolor="rgba(222, 209, 209, 0.18039216)" backcolor="#AB9898" uuid="972fca74-03e0-4232-bce4-d6293133af7c">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.layout.grid.x" value="-1"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.layout.grid.y" value="-1"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.layout.grid.weight.x" value="1.0"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.layout.grid.weight.y" value="1.0"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.layout.grid.rowspan" value="1"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.layout.grid.colspan" value="1"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.layout.grid.weight.fixed" value="true"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box padding="0">
                        <pen lineWidth="3.0" lineColor="#FC0E0A"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <frame>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="2" width="812" height="20" uuid="614c69d8-9284-4e6f-a60d-96254862241f">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <box padding="0">
                            <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#F511E2"/>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>

                            </reportElement>
                            <graphicElement>
                                <pen lineWidth="2.0"/>
                            </graphicElement>
                        </line>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="183" y="-4" width="400" height="20" forecolor="#000000" uuid="0e2cf1b7-6e3a-4d50-9607-1583f0fe8010">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Area Debito - Transato Medio]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <image hAlign="Right" vAlign="Middle">
                            <reportElement x="686" y="0" width="126" height="15" uuid="640ee669-cd3f-44b3-966d-10cf30c5ef1f">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{ATTR_PATH_ROOT}+"/themes/images/gruppo.png"]]></imageExpression>
                        </image>
                    </frame>
                    <frame>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="812" height="58" uuid="5f8c0f9b-128d-4de5-9f39-ea1241c0147f">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <box padding="0">
                            <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#F2FA19"/>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="5" y="1" width="414" height="18" forecolor="#000000" uuid="6a68590c-e3c8-4741-bceb-7e8f0e6b1ad0">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="10" isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Banca: " + $P{ATTR_DESC_ABI}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="5" y="15" width="678" height="12" forecolor="#000000" uuid="7b2e355e-226b-428a-a10a-9953adba0c37">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["ABI: " + $P{UID_ABI}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="5" y="27" width="678" height="12" forecolor="#000000" uuid="09c7a539-f6b0-4d60-b818-be612971fb02">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Periodo di riferimento: " + $P{ATTR_DESC_DATA_RIF}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </frame>
                    <frame>
                        <componentElement>
                            <reportElement stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="5" y="0" width="560" height="190" uuid="f0343158-6aa3-42b9-ab50-ccdf21e8333b">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table 17_TH"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table 17_CH"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table 17_TD"/>
                                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value=""/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">

                                    <jr:columnGroup width="560" uuid="ad5d3730-ea28-4332-8fa5-73c570b13850">
                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Columns [6]"/>
                                        <jr:column width="110" uuid="b72cc954-51ae-42d2-b3df-9cc3f9892c4f">
                                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                                            <jr:tableHeader style="Table 17_TH" height="0" rowSpan="1"/>
                                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 17_TD" height="14">
                                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                                                <box>
                                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                </box>
                                                <textField>
                                                    <reportElement style="StyleRowType3" x="0" y="0" width="110" height="14" uuid="9814fa84-2466-4cdd-ba72-1e5e64fad5e0"/>
                                                    <box leftPadding="3">
                                                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                    </box>
                                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                                                    </textElement>
                                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_DESC_RIGA_01}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                                </textField>
                                            </jr:detailCell>
                                        </jr:column>
                                        <jr:column width="90" uuid="2797f0bc-9ec0-48aa-9bb6-dd99f52a1a86">
                                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                                            <jr:tableHeader style="Table 17_TH" height="0" rowSpan="1"/>
                                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 17_TD" height="14">
                                                <box>
                                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                </box>
                                                <textField>
                                                    <reportElement style="StyleRowType3" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="14" uuid="175e2245-1115-4d88-a5a1-60451c92ca9f"/>
                                                    <box leftPadding="3">
                                                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                    </box>
                                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                                                    </textElement>
                                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_DESC_RIGA_02}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                                </textField>
                                            </jr:detailCell>
                                        </jr:column>
                                        <jr:column width="80" uuid="cf62130d-7a9f-4996-9890-764d2453032c">
                                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column4"/>
                                            <jr:tableHeader style="Table 17_TH" height="0" rowSpan="1"/>
                                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 17_TD" height="14">
                                                <box>
                                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                </box>
                                                <textField>
                                                    <reportElement style="StyleRowType" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="14" uuid="0c623985-9371-483c-bf94-20b395f23437"/>
                                                    <box rightPadding="3">
                                                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                    </box>
                                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                                                    </textElement>
                                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_VAL_MESE_02}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                                </textField>
                                            </jr:detailCell>
                                        </jr:column>

                                        <jr:column width="120" uuid="1b0d095f-7c87-40bb-ba8e-9fd839e14146">
                                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column6"/>
                                            <jr:tableHeader style="Table 17_TH" height="0" rowSpan="1"/>
                                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 17_TD" height="14">
                                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                                                <box>
                                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                </box>
                                                <textField>
                                                    <reportElement style="StyleRowType2" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="14" uuid="9f3bea46-c095-4f99-a35b-b892fafedc19"/>
                                                    <box rightPadding="3">
                                                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                    </box>
                                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                                                    </textElement>
                                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_VAL_CONFRONTO_MESE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                                </textField>
                                                <image>
                                                    <reportElement x="13" y="3" width="10" height="7" uuid="cc4fda9b-5613-4443-aed6-5cb51327ddf5">
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                                                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA["HEADER".equals($F{CODE_TIPO_RIGA})]]></printWhenExpression>
                                                    </reportElement>
                                                    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{ATTR_PATH_ROOT_Q1}]]></imageExpression>
                                                </image>
                                            </jr:detailCell>
                                        </jr:column>
                                    </jr:columnGroup>
                                </jr:columnGroup>
                            </jr:table>
                        </componentElement>
                        <componentElement>
                            <reportElement stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="590" y="0" width="220" height="190" uuid="303876e1-1cb4-4cac-858f-91f687af6d62">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table 18_TH"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table 18_CH"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table 18_TD"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
    <band height="156" splitType="Prevent">
                <frame>
                    <reportElement x="7" y="10" width="803" height="140" uuid="047b2838-0377-4ca8-93bd-98064677d457"/>
                    <componentElement>
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="-2" y="0" width="560" height="140" uuid="e37267b9-c35f-4091-aedf-dd071ce60377">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table 15_TH"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table 15_CH"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table 15_TD"/>
                            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value=""/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                            <datasetRun subDataset="TRANSATO_MEDIO_POS" uuid="b92ef83b-4c05-4e09-863c-2778fde09bc9">
                                <datasetParameter name="UID_REPORT_Q1">
                                    <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{UID_REPORT}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                                </datasetParameter>
                                <datasetParameter name="ATTR_PATH_ROOT_Q1">
                                    <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ATTR_PATH_ROOT}+"/themes/images/delta.png"]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                                </datasetParameter>
                                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                            </datasetRun>
                            <jr:columnGroup width="572" uuid="ced16577-dc75-4ac3-8707-ae751ace7363">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Columns [6]"/>
                                <jr:tableHeader style="Table 15_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                                    <textField>
                                        <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="0" width="572" height="30" forecolor="#008F47" uuid="c40c469e-44c2-4b23-af74-3adc490d14ce"/>
                                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                                        </textElement>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Transato Medio POS per carta Operativa"]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                </jr:tableHeader>
                                <jr:columnGroup width="572" uuid="78993b5a-0cb9-4197-a0c7-36d1b457de99">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Columns [6]"/>
                                    <jr:columnGroup width="572" uuid="41c367ff-0d84-4cfe-b19c-4ace5b502ed5">
                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Columns [6]"/>
                                        <jr:column width="114" uuid="e4ddf19b-31a9-4434-8ca3-1a40325e6cf4">
                                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 15_TD" height="14">
                                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                                                <box>
                                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                </box>

                                        <jr:column width="81" uuid="e4a0ac9a-4905-45b2-8ac8-d056090a1d72">
                                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column4"/>
                                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 15_TD" height="14">
                                                <box>
                                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                </box>
                                                <textField>
                                                    <reportElement style="StyleRowType" x="0" y="0" width="81" height="14" uuid="97456b47-b194-43a9-805d-96b4408a25be"/>
                                                    <box rightPadding="3">
                                                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                    </box>
                                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                                                    </textElement>
                                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_VAL_MESE_02}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                                </textField>
                                            </jr:detailCell>
                                        </jr:column>
                                        <jr:column width="81" uuid="6e06d035-f09c-4ef1-af1b-40d880b86464">
                                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column5"/>
                                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 15_TD" height="14">
                                                <box>
                                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                </box>
                                                <textField>
                                                    <reportElement style="StyleRowType" x="0" y="0" width="81" height="14" uuid="a6525600-6278-47e1-ac35-a82803b4809d"/>
                                                    <box rightPadding="3">
                                                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                    </box>
                                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                                                    </textElement>
                                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_VAL_MESE_03}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                                </textField>
                                            </jr:detailCell>
                                        </jr:column>
                                        <jr:column width="122" uuid="ea248000-cbf7-4762-b339-0473cad2ddf6">
                                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column6"/>
                                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 15_TD" height="14">
                                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                                                <box>
                                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                </box>
                                                <textField>
                                                    <reportElement style="StyleRowType2" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="14" uuid="75eb1057-667c-4def-ac72-a5fbaa7af92f"/>
                                                    <box rightPadding="3">
                                                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                    </box>
                                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                                                    </textElement>
                                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_VAL_CONFRONTO_MESE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                                </textField>
                                                <image>
                                                    <reportElement x="13" y="3" width="10" height="7" uuid="c097e238-9a58-40a3-a21c-cad899ca4453">
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                                                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA["HEADER".equals($F{CODE_TIPO_RIGA})]]></printWhenExpression>
                                                    </reportElement>
                                                    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{ATTR_PATH_ROOT_Q1}]]></imageExpression>
                                                </image>
                                            </jr:detailCell>
                                        </jr:column>
                                    </jr:columnGroup>
                                </jr:columnGroup>
                            </jr:columnGroup>
                        </jr:table>
                    </componentElement>
                    <componentElement>
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="583" y="0" width="220" height="140" uuid="f07fbb35-b061-4c55-8544-eb4ba66f50a2">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table 16_TH"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table 16_CH"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table 16_TD"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                            <datasetRun subDataset="TRANSATO_MEDIO_POS" uuid="32f38966-9caa-404c-8baf-367351b419a6">
                                <datasetParameter name="UID_REPORT_Q1">
                                    <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{UID_REPORT}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                                </datasetParameter>
                                <datasetParameter name="ATTR_PATH_ROOT_Q1">
                                    <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ATTR_PATH_ROOT}+"/themes/images/delta.png"]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                                </datasetParameter>
                                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                            </datasetRun>
                            <jr:columnGroup width="222" uuid="70d0333d-231d-4c14-9e3e-a49903520e74">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Columns [2]"/>
                                <jr:tableHeader style="Table 16_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                                <jr:columnGroup width="222" uuid="90dfef7d-1876-4ff2-969c-581772977174">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Columns [2]"/>
                                    <jr:columnGroup width="222" uuid="3ec6e035-cf3a-40b0-9de8-9c6004e10343">
                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Columns [2]"/>
                                        <jr:column width="93" uuid="7168adb6-d090-452e-8699-857685e6c6ec">
                                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 16_TD" height="14">
                                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                                                <box>
                                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                </box>
                                                <textField>
                                                    <reportElement style="StyleRowType" x="0" y="0" width="93" height="14" uuid="86024dab-6529-4795-a729-30d129f60cf6"/>
                                                    <box rightPadding="3">
                                                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                    </box>
                                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                                                    </textElement>
                                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_VAL_MESE_ANNO_PREC}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                                </textField>
                                            </jr:detailCell>
                                        </jr:column>
                                        <jr:column width="129" uuid="a925e4b3-d991-4580-881b-dad6f6e28db2">
                                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 16_TD" height="14">
                                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                                                <box>
                                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                </box>
                                                <textField>
                                                    <reportElement style="StyleRowType2" x="0" y="0" width="129" height="14" uuid="df0fe279-b9d8-4a5c-8a90-a4602ba7f260"/>
                                                    <box rightPadding="3">
                                                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                    </box>
                                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                                                    </textElement>
                                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_VAL_CONFRONTO_ESERCIZIO}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                                </textField>
                                                <image>
                                                    <reportElement x="13" y="3" width="10" height="7" uuid="2ee54c5c-84bf-487d-8664-d1e921d57c49">
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                                                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{CODE_TIPO_RIGA}.equals("HEADER")]]></printWhenExpression>
                                                    </reportElement>
                                                    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{ATTR_PATH_ROOT_Q1}]]></imageExpression>
                                                </image>
                                            </jr:detailCell>
                                        </jr:column>
                                    </jr:columnGroup>
                                </jr:columnGroup>
                            </jr:columnGroup>
                        </jr:table>
                    </componentElement>
                </frame>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Place the 3rd and 4th tables onto a separate band that has splitType="Prevent".

Comment: How can I do that? I have a summary band

Comment: You can use instead of the summary band a "fake" summary which is the group footer of a group that has a constant expression.  Group footers are multi band sections, so you can have several bands in the footer.

Comment: I have created a two group footer. The first one contains the 2nd one. The 1st group footer contains the 1st and the 2nd table and the 2nd one contains the 3rd and the 4th table. The 2nd band footer has as split type "Prevent". The table 1-2 are in the first page and the table 3-4 are in the 2nd page: Ok good!. But, even if table 1-2 have few record then table 3-4 remains in the 2nd page. I want instead a dynamic behaviour: in this case table  3-4 must remains in the 1st page.

Comment: with Prevent option table 3-4 always get printed in the 2nd page

Comment: How tall did you make the band and the table elements?  Post your JRXML so that we can see the exact layout.

Comment: I put an extract of my JRXML code

Comment: I maybe solve the issue. I put the property keepTogether and isStartNewPage in both groups and set the same height and width for the 4 tables. Then I deleted the frame which used to contain the first group. So, I have now two frame for the 4 tables. I added I page header as well. This way, I can print eventually the header in the 2nd page as well.